# How to find numbers less than N in unsorted tree

Tags: java, tree

How to find numbers less than N in unsorted tree. I was asked this question on an interview. My answer was that I should check all the nodes starting from the root or I will order the tree first.  Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an unsorted tree, you have to check every node by definition. If you were to check all but one node, it's impossible to tell whether you should increase your count by 1 or not without checking the last node.

Assuming you aren't allowed to modify the tree (most questions like this don't like you modifying the structure), you're looking at an `O(n)` solution for sure. However, the question then becomes what the best way to implement the solution is. Because it's a tree, the answer (and what the interviewer was looking for) is almost certainly **recursion**.

If we have a class that looks roughly like this (I'm assuming the general case of a tree. If it's a binary tree just replace children with left and right):

```
public class TreeNode{
    private int val;
    private Set<TreeNode> children;
}
```

Then we can add a smaller than N method to the class as such:

```
public class TreeNode{
    private int val;
    private Set<TreeNode> children;

    public int lessThanNCount(int n){
        int count = (val < n ? 1 : 0);
        if(children != null){
            for(TreeNode tn : children){
                count += tn.lessThanNCount(n);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

If your goal is to assemble the numbers, rather than get a count of them, then try this:

```
public class TreeNode{
    private int val;
    private Set<TreeNode> children;

    public ArrayList<Integer> lessThanNVals(int n){
        ArrayList<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(val < n) vals.add(val);
        if(children != null){
            for(TreeNode tn : children){
                vals.addAll(tn.lessThanNCount(n));
            }
        }
        return vals;
    }
}
```